# android recommend to a friend feature in android application

Tags: android

I want to add a "recommend to a friend" feature in my Android application. Can anyone help me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void recommendToFriend() {
    String emailTo = "";
    String emailCC = "";
    String defaultSubject = "MySuper Android application";
    String body = "http://market.android.com/details?id=" + getPackageName();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { emailTo });
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[] { emailCC });
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, defaultSubject);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.recommend_to_a_friend)));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your app, you can have any kind of control, like Button, Hyperlink, or dialog etc to implement this feature...